# How do I integrate Docusign into React app

Tags: reactjs, pdf, docusignapi, signature, docusignconnect

I need implement feature that will show a pdf file.

I would like can drag, drop to set position of signature area and catch coordinate like `{ x: 120, y: 120, page: 1 }`.

Does anyone have it working or have solution for it? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Is your React app a single-page app w/o a server component at all? all code is running client-side on the browser?

If that's the case, you need to use CORS in order to make API calls, and configure CORS to have the specific URLS related to where your app will reside.

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/single-page-applications-cors/ has all the information about this topic.

You can see code example on codePen and run it directly if you go to https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/vYVeqEL which is this code:

```
// Copyright © 2022 DocuSign, Inc.
// License: MIT Open Source https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

import {
    CallApi,
    ImplicitGrant,
    UserInfo
    // View the source at https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/LYBKqxb
} from "https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/LYBKqxb.js";
import {
    msg,
    htmlMsg,
    adjustRows,
    errMsg,
    workingUpdate,
    usingHttps
    // View the source at https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/QWBXYzX
} from "https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/QWBXYzX.js";

$(function () {
    // Set basic variables
    const dsReturnUrl = "https://docusign.github.io/jsfiddleDsResponse.html";
    const logLevel = 0; // 0 is terse; 9 is verbose
    let signingCeremonyWindow = null;

    // Example settings
    const docUrl = "https://docusign.github.io/examples/docs/anchorfields.pdf";
    const docViewUrl =
        "https://docusign.github.io/examples/docs/anchorfields_view.pdf";

    debugger; // uncomment with debugger open to find the right JS file.

    /*
     * The doit function is the example that is triggered by the
     * button. The user is already logged in (we have an access token).
     */
    let doit = async function doitf(event) {
        $("#doit").addClass("hide");
        if (!checkToken()) {
            // Check that we have a valid token
            return;
        }
        workingUpdate(true);
        const signer = {
            name: data.userInfo.name,
            email: data.userInfo.email,
        };
        const envelopeId = await createEnvelope(signer);
        if (envelopeId) {
            msg(`Envelope ${envelopeId} created.`);
        }
        $("#doit").removeClass("hide");
        workingUpdate(false);
    };
    doit = doit.bind(this);

    /*
     *  Create the envelope by completely specifying the envelope.
     *  Often the recommended alternative is to first create a template
     *  on the DocuSign platform, then reference the template when
     *  creating the envelope. See the other examples...
     */
    async function createEnvelope({ name, email, clientUserId }) {
        const docB64 = await data.callApi.getDocB64(docUrl); // fetch a document

        const req = {
            emailSubject: "Please sign the attached document",
            status: "sent",

            documents: [
                {
                    name: "Example document",
                    documentBase64: docB64,
                    fileExtension: "pdf",
                    documentId: "1",
                    documentFields: [
                        {
                            name: "doc field 1",
                            value: "val 1"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "doc field 2",
                            value: "val 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            recipients: {
                signers: [
                    {
                        email: email,
                        name: name,
                        clientUserId: clientUserId,
                        recipientId: "1",
                        tabs: {
                            signHereTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels"
                                }
                            ],
                            checkboxTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "180",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    tabLabel: "checkbox 1",
                                    tabGroupLabels: ["checkbox group"]
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "180",
                                    anchorYOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    tabLabel: "checkbox 2",
                                    tabGroupLabels: ["checkbox group"]
                                }
                            ],
                            tabGroups: [
                                {
                                    groupLabel: "checkbox group",
                                    groupRule: "SelectExactly",
                                    minimumRequired: "1",
                                    maximumAllowed: "1",
                                    validationMessage:
                                        "Please check one option",
                                    tabScope: "document",
                                    pageNumber: "1",
                                    documentId: "1"
                                }
                            ],
                            textTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "195",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    value: "I agree with license 1",
                                    locked: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size12",
                                    bold: "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "195",
                                    anchorYOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    value: "I agree with license 2",
                                    locked: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size12",
                                    bold: "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "20",
                                    anchorYOffset: "50",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    bold: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size14",
                                    fontColor: "NavyBlue",
                                    value:
                                        "Addendum\n‣ Item 1\n‣ Item 2\nThis is a multi-line read-only text field"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

        // Make the create envelope API call
        msg(`Creating envelope.`);
        const apiMethod = `/accounts/${data.userInfo.defaultAccount}/envelopes`;
        const httpMethod = "POST";
        const results = await data.callApi.callApiJson({
            apiMethod: apiMethod,
            httpMethod: httpMethod,
            req: req
        });
        if (results === false) {
            errMsg(data.callApi.errMsg);
            return false;
        }
        if (logLevel > 0) {
            htmlMsg(
                `<p>Envelope created. Response:</p><p><pre><code>${JSON.stringify(
                    results,
                    null,
                    4
                )}</code></pre></p>`
            );
        }
        return results.envelopeId;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /* Checks that the access token is still good.
     * Prompts for login if not
     */
    function checkToken() {
        if (data.implicitGrant.checkToken()) {
            // ok
            return true;
        } else {
            // not ok
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            $("#doit").addClass("hide");
            // reset everything
            msg("Please login");
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * Receives and dispatches incoming messages
     */
    let messageListener = async function messageListenerf(event) {
        if (!event.data) {
            return;
        }
        const source = event.data.source;
        if (source === "dsResponse") {
            signingCeremonyEnded(event.data);
            return;
        }
        if (source === "oauthResponse" && data.implicitGrant) {
            await implicitGrantMsg(event.data);
            return;
        }
    };
    messageListener = messageListener.bind(this);

    /*
     * Process incoming implicit grant response
     */
    async function implicitGrantMsg(eventData) {
        const oAuthResponse = data.implicitGrant.handleMessage(eventData);
        if (oAuthResponse === "ok") {
            if (await completeLogin()) {
                data.loggedIn();
            }
        } else if (oAuthResponse === "error") {
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            const errHtml = `<p class="text-danger">${data.implicitGrant.errMsg}</p>`;
            htmlMsg(errHtml);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Complete login process including
     * Get user information
     * Set up CallApi object
     * update the user
     */
    async function completeLogin() {
        data.userInfo = new UserInfo({
            accessToken: data.implicitGrant.accessToken,
            workingUpdateF: workingUpdate
        });
        const ok = await data.userInfo.getUserInfo();
        if (ok) {
            data.callApi = new CallApi({
                accessToken: data.implicitGrant.accessToken,
                apiBaseUrl: data.userInfo.defaultBaseUrl
            });
            if (logLevel === 0) {
                htmlMsg(
                    `<p><b>${data.userInfo.name}</b><br/>` +
                        `${data.userInfo.email}<br/>` +
                        `${data.userInfo.defaultAccountName}</p>`
                );
            } else {
                htmlMsg(
                    `<p><b>OAuth & UserInfo Results</b><br/>` +
                        `Name: ${data.userInfo.name}` +
                        ` (${data.userInfo.userId})<br/>` +
                        `Email: ${data.userInfo.email}<br/>` +
                        `Default account: ${data.userInfo.defaultAccountName}` +
                        ` (${data.userInfo.defaultAccount})<br/>` +
                        `Base URL: ${data.userInfo.defaultBaseUrl}</p>`
                );
            }
        } else {
            // Did not complete the login
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            const errHtml = `<p class="text-danger">${data.userInfo.errMsg}</p>`;
            htmlMsg(errHtml);
        }
        return ok;
    }

    /*
     * Login button was clicked
     */
    let login = async function loginf(event) {
        $("#login").addClass("hide");
        await data.implicitGrant.login();
    };
    login = login.bind(this);

    // Mainline
    let data = {
        implicitGrant: null,
        userInfo: null,
        callApi: null,
        loggedIn: () => $("#doit").removeClass("hide")
    };

    // The mainline
    if (usingHttps()) {
        adjustRows();
        data.implicitGrant = new ImplicitGrant({
            workingUpdateF: workingUpdate
        });

        window.addEventListener("message", messageListener);
        $("#btnOauth").click(login);
        $("#btnDoit").click(doit);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @inbar-gazit. Let me explain in detail that my mean, I have a react app allow:
- User selects a PDF document (in our app).
- A new frame opens (with DocuSign UI, if possible?).
- The user sets the position of the signature field. We will get this position to save to the API.
- After that the user clicks to open the envelope, and it will open the DocuSign site to sign the envelope with the signature coordinate we set above. [API sign each location](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sign-each-location)
Is it clear to you? Thank, have a nice day